# By adding two hexadecimal numbers the flags Z,N,V and C need to be found. I have found Z,N, C flags correct but V should be 0 instead of 1. Why?

Tags: assembly, hex, addition

FA
+AB
=A5 (Carry of 1, 1A5) C=1

A5=A*16+5*16^0=165 (is not between -127-128 so I think it is overflow and V=1 but the correct answer is V=0)

Other answers are correct:
A5=**1**0100101, which shows N flag is 1.
Also, Z flag is 0 because A5 is different from number 0.

Comment: [Edit] the question to include the assembly code that produces these results.

Comment: Yeap, I just did include them.

Comment: That's not a [mcve]; there's still no assembly instructions in your question.  Also, half the details are *only* in the title.  And you still haven't said what ISA this is for, I think CodeWarrior supports multi CPUs.  I'd be happy to remove my downvote if the question showed exactly which instructions led to this flag state.

Comment: Alright I will formulate the question differently.

Comment: What is ISA? @Peter Cordes

Comment: Name of the architecture, like ARM or m68k.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture

Comment: ISA instruction set architecture.  the instruction set.

Comment: Being addition, architectures that have the flags CNVZ get the same CNVZ results, so architecture isnt all that interesting here.  Subtraction would be as C can be inverted or not.  Some architectures dont have flags so you wouldnt be asking about any of those.  Not all architectures have all of those flags, and some architectures have more than one V and or C.  If you are using registers larger than 8 bits and not sign extending then that is a need to know architecture with some code but N would not be a 1 so we assume you are not doing that.  its not arm nor risc-v we can eliminate those

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FA + AB

```
        0
 11111010
+10101011
==========

111110100
 11111010
+10101011
==========
 10100101
```

The msbits of the operands are the same and the result is the same as those operands so it is not a signed overflow.  The other equivalent test is the carry in and carry out of the msbit are the same (both 1s) so no signed overflow.

```
0xFA + 0xAB = 0xA5
-6 + -85 = -91
```

that is not a signed overflow.

N is set because the msbit of the answer is set, C is set because of the carry out (unsigned overflow which is correct 250 + 171 = 421 ).  And the answer is not zero so Z = 0.

### Edit

The V bit is the SIGNED overflow bit, it only has meaning when the programmer considers these bits to be signed.  (for add and subtract the logic doesn't care/know about signed vs unsigned the logic is the same, that is the beauty of twos complement).

```
01111111  127
....
00000100  4
00000011  3
00000010  2
00000001  1
00000000  0
11111111 -1
11111110 -2
11111101 -3
....
10000001 -127
10000000 -128
```

When you the programmer consider the bits to be signed, and are using twos complement (or even sign/magnitude), then when you see the msbit set that means the number is negative.  So we assume here in this question you are talking about 8 bit numbers so 0xFA when considered a signed number is negative, how I figure out what that is in decimal is invert and add one then convert to decimal.

So 0xFA to 0x05 then add one 0x06  convert to decimal and add a negative sign so -6  0xAB is then 0x54+1 (with experience you can simply look at the hex number and invert it and write the inverted number) or 0x55 then I use my calculator -85.  -6 + -85 in decimal is -91, which can be represented in 8 bits because 8 bits, signed, can represent between +127 and -128, -91 falls in that range, so there is no SIGNED overflow.

We need to take the two's complement because we grew up thinking decimal and want to see the number as decimal so you use the above process, another way is type say FFFFA into my calculator then negate in hex mode and get some ffs some 00s then 6 so 0x06, a quicker way, on my calculator, then re-type just the 06 and convert to decimal.  FFFFAB (don't really need to sign extend it at all, just helps me when I do it) gives 55 then convert to decimal and negate.

So the WHY we have to do it is because if we want to understand it in our decimal minds and are doing it manually that is what we do, otherwise look it up in a table, use a program, etc. to "see" the negative number, same goes for positive if we want to "see" it in decimal then if the msbit is 0 we convert it as is, if 1 then invert add one then convert that and put a negative sign on it.  There is no reason for the processor to do this it wants the bits as is, it is only when we want to SEE what the processor is doing, we like to think in decimal.

Comment: Can you please give me some more hints about -6-85=-91? I understand that these numbers came from the 2's complement of the operands but why/do we always  have to take the 2's complement when the msb is 1?

Comment: We dont HAVE to, the processor doesnt need/want this, it is only when we as humans want to see what the bits mean in decimal which is what we are used to.  Which is what I did since you had not done the math right to see that -91 is between 127 and -127.   Since you asked for the V bit then you the human are interested in signed numbers 0xA5 is negative so do the correct conversion.  You have to choose am I interested in signed (V) or unsigned (C) and be consistent through the calculation.

Comment: @Albi see http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt for another version of the explanation in this answer.

Comment: Ahh now I understand thank you so much @old_timer. I am new in this field and that's why I make some questions which might be stupid to you guys :).  Very helpful link Peter Cordes. I just read it and got a full understanding. Thank you again!

Comment: not stupid at all, everyone should learn it and everyone needs to visualize it in their own way.